# Why am I getting an access violation exception in a pointer operation?

Tags: c++, .net-4.0

I'm using C++ Visual Studio .Net 4.0 on Windows 7.0 x64. This happens just on the first loop of the while statement.

```
int main()
{
  char *string = new char[11];

  string = "characters\0";

  toUppercase(string);

  return 0;
}



void toUppercase(char *stringPtr)
{
 while(*stringPtr != '\0')
 {
    if(*stringPtr >= 'a' && *stringPtr <= 'z')
    {
        *stringPtr = *stringPtr - 32; // this is the culprit
    }

    ++stringPtr;    
 }
}
```

Comment: If you're using the .NET Framework, why in the world are you re-implementing a function to convert a string to uppercase?

Comment: Have you checked that the *stringPtr actually contains \0 at the end ?

Comment: Was it a read or write AV?  Is the string properly null-terminated?  How did you call toUppercase, exactly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suspect you're doing something like this:

```
toUppercase("test");
```

The problem is `"test"` is an array of `const char`, not `char`, so cannot be modified. However, due to a terribly stupid deprecated special conversion, a string literal can be treated as `char*` anyway.

(Your function also fails to test for `toUppercase(0)`.)

Comment: if can you please state what can I do with this? Thanks.

Comment: @Lemuel: Do with what? If you're doing what my answer shows in your code, don't. You need to have a modifiable buffer: `char buff[] = "test"; toUppercase(buff);`

Answer (score 2):

My guess would be that you are passing to that function a pointer to a string that resides in read-only memory. However, you would need to share the surrounding code -- i.e., how you actually call this method -- to pinpoint the problem.

EDIT: In view of the above, here's one way to get this working:

```
char* str = strdup("hello world");
toUppercase(str);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get #AV if memory isn't writeable:

```
toUppercase((char*)"str");
```